# "Solve" with problem "Solve::ivar: "-1+t is not a valid variable.""

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[{Ee1*ek1 + g*h*(1 + r) + j1*h*ek2 == ek1, Ee2*ek2 + j1*h*ek1 + j2*h*ek3 == ek2, 
  Ee3*ek3 + j2*h*ek2 == ek3}, {r}]
```

want to get `r` in the 3 eqs.

but get error with： `Solve::ivar: "-1+t is not a valid variable."`
can't figure out what's going on 
and want to know how to rewrite it to get "r" written by vars above,thx

Comment: Try `Clear[r]` and report back.

Comment: I get nothing 
,

out={ } ,

what is that mean

Comment: @WinnieTseng That means that your system of equations has no general solutions, i.e. solutions that are always valid independently of the values of the parameters. If you would like to find solutions that are valid for **only some values of the parameters**, try `Reduce` instead of `Solve`.

Comment: Check documentation for the `MaxExtraConditions` option to `Solve`.

Answer (score 2):

You can first eliminate the h:

```
s1 = Eliminate[{Ee1*ek1 + g*h*(1 + r) + j1*h*ek2 == ek1, 
   Ee2*ek2 + j1*h*ek1 + j2*h*ek3 == ek2, 
   Ee3*ek3 + j2*h*ek2 == ek3}, {h}]
```

and in a next step Reduce for r:

```
Reduce[s1, {r}]
```

then you´ll get the r as a value (-1 in one case) or expressed with the other variables.